# How to implement timeline range slider in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider, range, timeline

I want a view for timeline with horizontal scroll views ( ViewPager example ).

I would have pages from 1970 to 2000. And I can jump on to particular view by selecting from timeline.

Can someone suggest me if we have this kind of library in android.

https://www.timetoast.com/timelines/hip-hop-then-and-now

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that may help you achieve this timeline type of layout. It has both horizontal and vertical alignments.

Have a look : [Timeline-View](https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View)